# Anti Aliasing and Interpolation Quality on image - Image does not get shown

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, interpolation, cgcontext

I get my image from the internet and add it to a my tableView imageView. I works like a charm, but when the picture is to big, it gets pixelated. Therefore I implemented Interpolation Quality and Anti-Aliasing. 
But the image doesn't get displayed when I use either of those methods. 
I don't get an 0x0 error or anything like that. So I am pretty stumbed.

```
UIImage *image_ = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TableText7]]];
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image_.size.width,image_.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), true); 

image_ = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[cell.imageView setImage:image_];
[cell setNeedsLayout];
```